# Function to return all related data from json list using any given key

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following json data about experts.

```
result={
        "experts":[
  {
    "thumbnail": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=small_photo&user=JicYPdAAAAAJ&citpid=2",
    "name": "Geoffrey Hinton",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=JicYPdAAAAAJ",
    "author_id": "JicYPdAAAAAJ",
    "email": "Verified email at cs.toronto.edu",
    "affiliations": "Emeritus Prof. Comp Sci, U.Toronto & Engineering Fellow, Google",
    "cited_by": 638900,
    "interests": [
      {
        "title": "machine learning",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Amachine_learning",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:machine_learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "psychology",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Apsychology",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:psychology"
      },
      {
        "title": "artificial intelligence",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aartificial_intelligence",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:artificial_intelligence"
      },
      {
        "title": "cognitive science",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Acognitive_science",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:cognitive_science"
      },
      {
        "title": "computer science",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Acomputer_science",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:computer_science"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "thumbnail": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=small_photo&user=kukA0LcAAAAJ&citpid=3",
    "name": "Yoshua Bengio",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=kukA0LcAAAAJ",
    "author_id": "kukA0LcAAAAJ",
    "email": "Verified email at umontreal.ca",
    "affiliations": "Professor of computer science, University of Montreal, Mila, IVADO, CIFAR",
    "cited_by": 605714,
    "interests": [
      {
        "title": "Machine learning",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Amachine_learning",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:machine_learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "deep learning",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Adeep_learning",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:deep_learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "artificial intelligence",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aartificial_intelligence",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:artificial_intelligence"
      }
    ]
  }
        ]
    }
```

Given an input of "author_id" I want to get all the data related to that "author_id".For example if I give the input "JicYPdAAAJ" i want to get the thumbnail,name,email,link,affilations,etc and all the related with that author id from the list of Json data.In this case all the related data about Geoffrey Hinton will be returned.
How do I write a function to achieve this?So far I tried using key value matching but the logic does not seem to work.
Hope somebody helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the list and find the author id:

```
def get_expert_details(author_id: str) -> dict:
    for expert in result['experts']:
        if expert['author_id'] == author_id:
            return expert
```

Comment: Thanks!.Didnt realise it was that simple.I was over complicating things

Comment: Happy to help. If you have performance issues consider using numpy vectorize or converting the list to a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the all authors and check if 'author_id' is the same as you provided. example:

```py
SEARCH_ID = 'kukA0LcAAAAJ'
for enum, expert in enumerate(result['experts']):
    if result['experts'][enum]['author_id'] == SEARCH_ID:
        print(result['experts'][enum]['name'])  # PRINT key NAME
```

which returns
`Yoshua Bengio`
you can edit this code to print whatever data you want.

Comment: No need to use enumerate as you can iterate directly on the list items

Comment: @SiP is right. Also, following [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), `ENUM` should **not** be named in uppercase, which is used for constants

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
answer = [expression for item in iterable if condition == True]
```

In your case:

```
answer = [x for x in result["experts"] if x["author_id"] == "JicYPdAAAAAJ"]
```

Note - this will return a list with the data you are looking for.

Also you have an error in your question. The id mentioned in the text, "JicYPdAAAJ", is different to the id in your data, "JicYPdAAAAAJ"

Comment: In this case list comprehension is less suitable. List comprehension will iterate over the whole list even after the relevant item is found eating resources